# testthat: handling both warning and value

Tags: r, testthat

What's the best way to handle calls that generate a warning but then also return a value?

e.g.

```
> require(testthat)
> expect_warning(log(-1))
> expect_equal(log(-1), NaN)
Warning message:
In log(-1) : NaNs produced
```

I want to write the test such that the call to log(-1) should both (a) generate a warning and (b) return the value NaN.  The way above works, but seeing the "Warning message:" at the bottom might confuse people.  Should I suppress warnings temporarily?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
require(testthat)
expect_warning(val <- log(-1))
expect_true(is.nan(val))
```

Comment: I know the last line does work, but it feels slightly cleaner as `expect_true(is.nan(val))`.  `expect_equal(val, NaN)` passing relies upon `all.equal(NaN, NaN)` being true, which is a dubious design decision.

Comment: @RichieCotton or maybe `expect_identical(val, NaN)` which seems a little safer

Answer (score 0):

One great way to deal with value, message and warning is to use the adverb [`purrr::quietly`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/quietly.html) like that:

```
## R/foo.r
foo <- function() {
  message("This is a message")
  warning("This is a warning")
  "This is a result"
}
```

```
test_that("foo works", {
  qfoo <- purrr::quietly(foo)
  qfoo_call <- qfoo()
  expect_equal(qfoo_call$result, "This is a result")
  expect_equal(qfoo_call$message, "This is a message")
  expect_equal(qfoo_call$warning, "This is a warning")
})
```

---

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547934/how-to-mute-messages-and-warnings-with-testthat-when-they-are-expected) to see all the benefits of this approach.