# How to mute messages and warnings with testthat when they are expected

Tags: r, testthat

In order to develop a package, I am using `testthat`. I want to test if my functions send proper messages and warnings. I want to test the results of functions at the same time. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
## R/foo.r
foo <- function() {
  message("This is a message")
  warning("This is a warning")
  "This is a result"
}
```

I write these tests:

```
## tests/testthat/test-foo.R

test_that("foo works", {
  expect_equal(foo(), "This is a result")
  expect_message(foo(), "This is a message")
  expect_warning(foo(), "This is a warning")
})
```

But now when I run the tests I have this:

```
Loading testWarnMess
Testing testWarnMess
v |  OK F W S | Context
/ |   0       | foo                                                                           This is a message
v |   3   2   | foo [0.3 s]                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning (test-foo.R:2:3): foo works
This is a warning
Backtrace:
 1. testthat::expect_equal(foo(), "This is a result") test-foo.R:2:2
 4. testWarnMess::foo()

Warning (test-foo.R:3:3): foo works
This is a warning
Backtrace:
 1. testthat::expect_message(foo(), "This is a message") test-foo.R:3:2
 7. testWarnMess::foo()
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

== Results ===================================================================================
Duration: 0.3 s

[ FAIL 0 | WARN 2 | SKIP 0 | PASS 3 ]
This is a message
```

How to prevent messages and warnings to be seen in the test results when I am expecting them to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One great way to do that is to use the adverb `purrr::quietly`.

```
test_that("foo works", {
  qfoo <- purrr::quietly(foo)
  qfoo_call <- qfoo()
  expect_equal(qfoo_call$result, "This is a result")
  expect_equal(qfoo_call$message, "This is a message")
  expect_equal(qfoo_call$warning, "This is a warning")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `expect_warning()` and `expect_message()` states:

> In the 3rd edition, these functions match (at most) a single condition. All additional and non-matching (if regexp or class are used) conditions will bubble up outside the expectation. If these additional conditions are important you'll need to catch them with additional expect_message()/expect_warning() calls; if they're unimportant you can ignore with suppressMessages()/suppressWarnings().

So there should be no need to bloat your package with dependencies. Here's one way to do it:

```r
test_that("foo works", {
  expect_warning(
    expect_message(foo(), "This is a message"),
    "This is a warning"
  )
  expect_equal(
    suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(foo())),
    "This is a result"
  )
})
```

If your case is much more complex than this, you may prefer to use `expect_snapshot()` instead.

Comment: Very interesting (upvoted) but not sure this is a better call. For two reasons: (1) Decrease readability, (2) `foo` need to be called twice. From the dependency point of view, is it possible to use a package in the test part that is not required to be part of the dependcies of the final produced package?

Comment: IIRC, if you're using a package just on tests and vignettes (also examples, according to [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages)), you could list it under "Suggests" so it's like a soft dependency.